# HTML entity encode is not working with esc_html() and wp_localize_script()

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to pass JavaScript object using wp_localize_script() function and expecting an entitiy encoded string in the object. Below is the sample:

```
$params = array('str' => esc_html('this string has a < symbol and unclosed <td> tag'), 'change' => false);

wp_localize_script( 'custom_setup_js', 'custom_js_params', $params );
```

What is output?

```
/* <![CDATA[ */ var custom_js_params = {"str":"this string has a < symbol and unclosed <td> tag","change":""}; /* ]]> */
```

What is expected?

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var custom_js_params = {"str":"this string has a &lt; symbol and unclosed &lt;td&gt; tag","change":""};
/* ]]> */
```

What am I doing wrong or am I misunderstanding anything? Since I need the JavaScript object to contain the encoded HTML in the string. I have already tried the same without using the esc_html() function yet no success.

PS: The string is coming from user input thus needs escaping. I have just skipped it to state the problem easier.

Comment: Is it really not escaped? I usually look at the page source to make sure.

Comment: @Michael What have you gotten in the page source and which browser? The string is escaping fine. However, the JS object rendered by `wp_localize_script()` function doesn't have the encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your HTML entities get decoded again is because `wp_localize_script` calls the method `localize` in `class.wp-scripts.php` which has the line:

```
$l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Additionally, your string is passed to `wp_json_encode`, which will do some sanitizing before doing a PHP `json_encode`.

In other words, your string is first sanitized by WP and then properly escaped by PHP. Depending on your use case, it might not be necessary to do any additional encoding or escaping yourself.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218776), it doesn't go beyond producing a safer JSON encoded string. Anyway, is there any option to keep the encoded string in the JS object intact at the server level/PHP?

Comment: I guess that's right, I was assuming that JSON encoding would be sufficient. If you need your encoded HTML entities, you would probably want to use your own function, not `wp_localize_script`. You would just need to make sure that your javascript object is loaded before your script that relies on it.

Comment: Yes. JS object in the header, script in the footer.